# Can I score PMML with Ruby?

Tags: ruby, r, pmml

I've been googling, and most of the efforts around PMML and data modeling are focussed around Java. Is there a way to score it with Ruby?

I'm currently considering using https://github.com/clbustos/rinruby to have direct access to R... load the .rda model, call the `predict()` method in R with some predefined variables, and save the result to a regular 'ol Ruby variable. Seems pretty straight forward, no?

So, can Ruby handle PMML? Is my RinRuby solution production-worthy? Any suggestions, or reading material I should checkout would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I'm working on a gem called [scoruby](https://github.com/asafschers/scoruby), that loads PMML models and scores on production.
For now it only supports naive bayes, decision tree, random forest and gradient boosted models but I would love to support new models by demand.

Regarding RinRuby not sure if its main purpose is scoring on production, and I don't know about its time performance.